# Set different color to specific time slots in Fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, css, fullcalendar

I'm working with the agendaDay view in Fullcalendar. I have a function that blocks when the user clicks in specific time slots, in specific days (it is recorded in database). I wonder how can I set a different color only for certain time slots in a day, specifically, the lines I've blocked. How can I identify a specific time line to change it's color? In my context, the businessHours property is not what I need, but is almost like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to find the specific rows in `agendaDay` view and then change their background color. The time value is in the `span` of each `tr`, so we need to find that first and then color the row if it falls between our required timeslot.

You can achieve it by using something like this:

```
$('tr').find('span').each( function(){
   var timeSlot = $(this).text();
   if(timeSlot> 13 && timeSlot < 18)    //Change 13 and 18 according to what you need
      $(this).closest('tr').css('background-color', '#000');
});
```

Comment: To this code work out correctly, you need to configure the time slots to show the label of time for the lines. If we put the length of the slots as 00:15:00, 00: 00: 30: 00, or 00:45:00 the  labels the lines will not appear. You must add one second to the end of the slot duration: 00:15:01.